# OnResume() not called when using MaterialContainerTransform

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, material-design

I am trying to use `MaterialContainerTransform`. I have this code in `FragmentA`

```
FragmentB fragmentB = FragmentB.newInstance("shared_element_container");
fragmentB.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new MaterialContainerTransform());
getParentFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .setReorderingAllowed(true)
        .addSharedElement(view,"shared_element_container")
        .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragmentB, FragmentB.class.getSimpleName())
        .addToBackStack(FragmentB.class.getSimpleName())
        .commit();
        getParentFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

And I found that `onResume()` in `FragmentB` is not called. If I comment out `fragmentB.setSharedElementEnterTransition(new MaterialContainerTransform());`, `onResume()` will get called normally. Did I miss something or is this a bug? I am using `com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha03`.

Comment: What version of Fragments are you using?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am using `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`

Comment: No, what **version** of the fragment dependency are you using? It may be helpful to include your `dependencies` block from your `build.gradle` file

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you. I was using `1.2.5`. I have changed it to `1.3.0-beta01` and it works now.